# Angular Library using HTML of component of app

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, angular-library

I am implementing my first angular library.

I want to achieve a header and footer library for angular. The problem is, that it should have the html of the app it is used in. Below you can find the sketch of the HTML code, I want to achieve.

```
//some header
<pageContent>
</pageContent>
//some footer
```

The `pageContent.component` should come from the app where the library is embedded.
How do I achieve this?

#### EDIT:

I am trying to elaborate more:

In my angular library I have a component, which should have a header and a footer. Furthermore, it should show the main content of the page. Therefore, the library needs the input of the `pageContent.component`. How do I achieve this?

Comment: Can you elaborate more ? May be its just me, but I am unable to understand clearly

Comment: Done :-) I hope its clear now

Comment: Thanks Dieter. Take a look at the answer & demo code. Since you are new angular, I have put some routing in it to make it more closer to real life example.

Comment: Sorry for being late on my answer, since I had other work to do unfortunately. We are experimenting with Angular Libraries atm. But the tip with content projection did it :-)

Comment: Glad to hear that ! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank you for adding more details. [Take a look at this demo code for reference](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng-content-projection-agnktp?file=app%2Fapp.component.html)

As you can see, I have used `ng-content` in `canvas.component.html` as below:

```
<div id='border'>
   <h3>header</h3>
    <ng-content>
      <!-- Dynamic content goes here -->
    </ng-content>
    <h3>footer</h3>
</div>
```

The canvas component contains the `header` and `footer` as you wanted. I have put some routing in this example to make it more close to what you are looking for.

I hope this has helped you. Cheers!